# Why are my environment settings not being detected when I deploy my ASP.NET Core web application to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I'm trying to define some environment variables in my web application.  I host my site on Azure which has a staging deployment slot that the site goes to first, then, if the changes are signed off it's released to production.

The URLs for these two places are:

Production

```
"BaseUrl": "https://mycompany.azurewebsites.net"
```

Staging

```
"BaseUrl": "https://mycompany-staging2n1h.azurewebsites.net"
```

I want my `appsettings.Staging.json` file to be used when the site hits the staging area and then once it's released to production I want it to use `appsettings.json`.

> It's my understanding that, if you don't define a production
> `appsettings.Production.json` file in your applicataion it defaults to
> `appsettings.json`.

So, I created a `appsettings.Staging.json` file within my application which contains a different connection string from the production environment.

***appsettings.json***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",    
    "BaseUrl": "https://mycompany.azurewebsites.net"       
  },      
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyCompanyConnection": "production connection string"        
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***appsettings.Staging.json***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "BaseUrl": "https://mycompany-staging2n1h.azurewebsites.net"
  },     
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyCompanyConnection": "staging connection string"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I then went into the `launchSettings.json` file to set this up as follows:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx",
      "sslPort": xxxx
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyCompany": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": { 
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "MyCompany Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I deploy my application to Azure and it hits the staging area, it's looking at the wrong connection string which means it's not using the correct appsettings file.  Have I missed a step or set something up incorrectly?

Comment: Its up to you of course, but I find it easier to use the app service configuration. Those are pulled in as environment variables and will override anything in a json file.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`on Azure - for an app service, it's in the Configuration section:

[image: Image of app service configuration showing environment]

(Changes to `launchSettings.json` have no effect when an app is deployed, it's only used by Visual Studio)

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says:

*To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:*

1. `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`
2. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` *when ConfigureWebHostDefaults is called. The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call ConfigureWebHostDefaults. The* `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` *value overrides* `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`

*The following values are provided by the framework:*

- *Development : The launchSettings.json file sets* `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` *to Development on the local machine.*
- *Staging*
- *Production : The default if* `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` *and* `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` *have not been set.*